Book Identification: Chapter Book about Father's Alcoholism
I remember reading this book way back when I was a kid. Though, but I can't remember when. I believe it was a chapter book. I don't remember much, but this is what I can piece together about it:
The main character is a girl. I believe she is not older than a tween, but is not younger than let's say a 4th grader. I believe she has a younger brother who is there throughout the story with her, but I could be wrong. Her father had some alcohol issues, which is why she hasn't see him for long. However, he is seemingly doing well now, and for some reason she and her brother go stay with him since he's alright now. For some time at her dad's, life is good; everything is normal. I remember one thing definitely: she receives a sort of "tip" from somewhere or someone (I can't remember who) in which it (or they) says her dad would previously hide alcohol bottles around the house to hide the fact that he was still an alcoholic. So, she checks around the house, with her brother I think (but she might not even have a brother, idk), and finds the alcohol bottles around the house. I also remember the ending: she spots him at a bar (I think she's with someone else, or could just be roaming around, or could possibly be at the bar with her dad too) with beer or some sort of alcohol. She is shocked at her dad's betrayal and return to alcohol. I think in the last several lines of the novel, she confronts him in which he admits to his return to his alcoholism, or says something about how it's just "one time" and that he's sober.
If you can help me in determining the name of this book, you're a legend 

What's a 'chapter book'? Most books are divided into chapters, if that is what you mean.  As a non-American , I don't understand 'she is not older than a tween, but is not younger than let's say a 4th grader'.

Hi Alex, you said you read the book way back when you were a kid - can you tell us how long ago that was. Do you remember any other details? Was there a mom in the story, for example?

That would put her between 9 and 12 most likely.

@KateBunting Maybe "chapter book" is more often used in North America (especially when talking about kid's books), not commonly used in UK. It should refer to more complicated books with more than one chapter for toddlers, as compared with easier books such as picture books for younger children.

I had to look up the subject myself   "A chapter book is a story book intended for intermediate readers, generally age 7–10.[1][2] Unlike picture books for beginning readers, a chapter book tells the story primarily through prose rather than pictures. Unlike books for advanced readers, chapter books contain plentiful illustrations. The name refers to the fact that the stories are usually divided into short chapters, ..."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_book
